# generate ios 10 universal app splash screen sizes and filenames, iPhone SE

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-universal-app, launch-screen, launchimage

I am making an iOS 10 ONLY Universal App. Being a developer with poor image-handling skills, it has become too troublesome to generate the splash screen images for me. I guess that's some work for the "designers".
Nevertheless, i have to do it and I need help because what i have made doesn't work fine with the iPhone SE.

I don't care about older devices and operating system versions, but i want to cover every device that can run iOS 10. so forget iOS 6,7,8,9.
Btw, i am using Xcode 8, so forget all about Xcode 5,6,7.

There's too much of confusing content for new developers often wasting their time while they read about older versions and which might not be quite applicable anymore.

I have read the following posts/guides already.

1. [What are the sizes used for the iOS application splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634898/what-are-the-sizes-used-for-the-ios-application-splash-screen)
2. [Image resolution for new iPhone 6 and 6+, @3x support added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781422/image-resolution-for-new-iphone-6-and-6-3x-support-added)
3. [Image sizes required to support all iPhone devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843579/image-sizes-required-to-support-all-iphone-devices)
4. [How to handle image scale on all the available iPhone resolutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969533/how-to-handle-image-scale-on-all-the-available-iphone-resolutions)
5. [Use vector artwork for iOS launch image in asset catalog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307675/use-vector-artwork-for-ios-launch-image-in-asset-catalog)

The first SO post is so outdated, people are talking about iOS 6 & 7,
and iPhones 6, 6+, 5S, 5, 5C, 4S, 4 and the various iPads.
But no one mentioned/talks about **iPhone SE**.

The second SO post is also quite outdated, people are talking about iOS 7 & 8, and iPhone 6 and 6+ are mentioned.

Even though i figure out the size, there is a **filenaming/convention** issue.
I am looking for a table that *clearly states* the filename, image size(resolution) and the devices it will be applied to.

As usual, Apple's documentation provides good detail about image resolution but nothing about filename.

link -> https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/

1. I wonder if the filenames matter? I can easily modify the `Contents.json` file i think.
2. Is there some tool where i can provide my logo in **`vector (SVG)`** format
   and it gives me all the splash screens with my logo in the center (with the correct filenames!)
3. I believe the iPhone 5/5C/6/6S/6+/7/7+ are the only 7 iPhones that support iOS 10. (i checked Wikipedia) Did i miss something?
4. In a universal app, is making images for iPads **mandatory**?
5. Why doesn't everyone use and everyone allow using vector images directly? I hope i can use SVG, and it is easy enough, it looks like currently that is infeasible. correct if i am wrong.